# UISegmentedControl not firing UIControlEventValueChanged

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm working on the IOS Programming: Big Nerd Ranch Guide Chapter 5 Silver Challenge and am wracking my brain trying to hook up the UISegmentedControl's change event.

Controller.m's initializer contains:

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
    action:@selector(onChangeSegment:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Controller.m also contains:

```
- (void) onChangeSegment:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Phew made it!");
}
```

Controller.h contains:

```
@interface
//...

- (void) onChangeSegment:(id)sender;
@end
```

All appears to be in place, however when the active segment is changed from the UI, onChangeSegment is never messaged.  This is the case with either the simulator or my iPhone4S (IOS7 and XCode 5).

Any help or direction is appreciated.  Please let me know if I can supply more details.

Answer (score 3):

Please do a

```
NSLog(@"segmentedControl: %@", segmentedControl);
```

before your target action adding. Its possible you're trying to addTarget: to a nil object. If you're doing this via Interface Builder, the addTarget should be done in the -viewDidLoad: method.

What I did in a sample app was:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(change:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)change:(UISegmentedControl *)control{
    NSLog(@"changed!");
}
```

The Segmented Control was created using IB and linked to the view controller's header.

Comment: Thanks, moved it to viewDidLoad and it works.  The debugger could have helped me there easily :)

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Controller.m's **initializer** contains:

In initializer you don't have IBOutlets from XIB so segmentedControl == nil at that time and method call does nothing. Views are usually configured in **-viewDidLoad** method where IBOutlets are guaranteed to be loaded from xib. So simply move

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
action:@selector(onChangeSegment:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

to **-viewDidLoad** method. Other things seem to be ok.